# SQL to split result in chunks

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, split, count

I need help in writing a Oracle SQL query to achieve the following.
Let say I have a query that returns about 110,000 sorted unique number values, not necessary from 1 to 110,000, could be any unique numbers and not consecutive. I would like to split them into chunks of 25,000 each and the last chunk holds the rest, 10,000 in this example. and get the min and max of each chunk.
Thanks in advance.

John T.

For this example, I expected to have 5 chunks and the min and max values of each chunk.
Let's ASSUME these numbers are from 1 to 110,000:

```
Chunk      Min     Max
1          1       25,000
2          25,001  50,000
3          50,001  75,000
4          75,001  100,000
5          100,001 110,000
```

Comment: Does your table have an identity column?  If not you can see if oracle supports row_number functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```
with tbl as (
   /* sample data */
   select round(dbms_random.value() * 1000000) n
   from dual
   connect by level <= 110000
)
select chunk_no, count(*) cnt, min(n), max(n)
from (
   select n, floor((row_number() over(order by n) - 1) / 25000) chunk_no
   from tbl
)
group by chunk_no
order by chunk_no
```